# Customize default taskbar tasks in Windows 7 taskbar "jump list"

Tags: winapi, windows-7, windows-shell, taskbar

I have a program A.exe that bootstraps another process B.exe, passing dynamic command line arguments to B.exe.  The default Windows 7 taskbar task list will provide an option to start another instance of B.exe as its top option.  For example: http://cl.ly/image/2C1X2g1A2K0k the top option will open another instance of the command window.

What I desire is to customize this default task list - via Win32/Shell APIs - so that the top option actually opens A.exe instead of B.exe.  Is this possible?  This also goes for when the application is "pinned"; the pinned button should point to, and load A.exe.  Because B.exe needs dynamic command line parameters that are determined by A.exe, this is a requirement.  B.exe has no knowledge of A.exe.

If this is not possible, is there any other workaround (i.e. shell links, shortcuts, etc) that can be used to get this functionality?  Or is there simply a way to disable that task list altogether?

Thanks in advance.  If this question is not clear, please let me know and I'll update the description.

Comment: For pinning, you can use the System.App­User­Model.Relaunch­Command property. Sample program [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/01/10170113.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A good solution to this problem was to use a shortcut (.lnk) file, combined with the `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` flag [as explained on the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx%20%22as%20explained%20on%20the%20MSDN%20page).  Windows will use the shortcut as its taskbar task item for starting new instances of the application (the top entry on the task list) as well as when the application is pinned to the taskbar.

For example, assuming B.lnk points to B.exe, we can put into A.exe:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
siStartInfo.lpTitle = (LPTSTR)L"C:\Path\to\B.lnk";
siStartInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME;

CreateProcess(NULL,
              (LPTSTR)L"C:\Path\to\B.exe",
              NULL,
              NULL,
              TRUE,
              CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
              NULL,
              NULL,
              &siStartInfo,
              &piProcInfo);
```

Hope that helps someone with a similar niche use case.